# ElasticSearchHadoop throwing unauthorised exception

Tags: elasticsearch-hadoop

We are upgrading from Elastic 6.3 to 7.8 version. We are using- elastic Hadoop to upload the data in elastic index using scala spark.

We are getting unauthorized exception while uploading the data. The same code working fine with 6.3 version. The exception is thrown by rest client while making HEAD call to "/indexName" path.

We are using:

EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(rdd. indexName/indextype, elasticConfig) method.

Exception message :

[HEAD] on [indexName] failed. server [serverName] retuned [401| unauthorized]

When I hit the request from postname it works fine.